# How to sum value from an Array in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
     array:3 [▼
       0 => array:3 [▼
          "product_id" => "5"
          "quantity" => "1"
          "price" => "250"
     ]

      1 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => "6"
        "quantity" => "4"
        "price" => "1240"
     ]

   2 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => null
        "quantity" => null
        "price" => null
    ]
]
```

I have an array. I want to sum quantity & price from this array. How can I do that?

For example: sum of quantity will be 2+2+2 = 6 & price will be 500+700+620 = 1820

Comment: You have a picture

Comment: Sum all quantity and price together? For example you expect a result of sum = 1826? Also please include the array as text, not an image.

Comment: Sum all quantity and price diffrently not together. From above picture, sum of quantity will be 2+2+2 = 6 & price will be 500+700+620 = 1820 .. how can I do that?

Comment: edit your question to include your last comment of how you want to perform the calculation and exclude the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want sum all things together:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($arr as $a) {
    $quantity = $a['quantity'] ?? 0;
    $price = $a['price'] ?? 0;
    $sum += $quantity * $price;
}
```

but with your edit you should do like this:

```
$sumQuntity = 0;
$sumPrice = 0;
foreach($arr as $a) {
    $sumQuntity += $a['quantity'] ?? 0;
    $sumPrice += $a['price'] ?? 0;
}
```

Comment: I applied your code & I got this error "Trying to get property 'quantity' of non-object"

Comment: @ihprince i editted my answer, please take a look again